# Copy and Pasting VBA Code to other Modules in VBE for Excel Gives Out of Memory Error

Tags: excel, vba7, excel-365, vba6

I am attempting to copy and paste VBA code from a module in an Excel workbook to a new module in another workbook.  When doing so, I get an "Out of Memory" error.  This is something I have done countless times as a VBA developer, so why this message is happening is confusing me.

The code being copied is approximately 22,000 lines in length.  I have another module in the same workbook where I copied in approximately 33,000 lines of VBA code from another workbook also.  I can continue to make more modules of the code that is 33,000 lines without any errors, so why a shorter block of code is making the error is confusing.

Once I get the Out of Memory error, I cannot even type in more lines of code anywhere in the VBE.  If I try, it just gives me the error.

Other Facts:

1. I tried copying shorter segments of the code into the new module and slowly piece it all together.  However, when I get to about a total of 15,000 lines of code copied in, it refuses to accept any more.
2. The two workbooks I am working with are a set of 10 that are all linked together via formulas.  I have been using these files for 7 years, and made many VBA modifications, with no errors like this.
3. I have rebooted my PC several times.
4. I have cleared my clipboard many times.
5. I have Open and Repaired both files many times.
6. I am using 64 Bit Excel 365 on Windows 11 PC. (Build 2308)  Both files are "*.xlsm".
7. I tried doing this on another PC with 32 Bit Excel 365 on Windows 11.  Same results.
8. I've tried exporting the VBA module and importing it into the other workbook.  Same results.
9. I've copy and pasted the VBA code to NotePad (and Notepad++) to remove any special characters that would cause issues.  And then tried pasted it into Excel from there. This hasn't helped.
10. I've tried when both Excel files are open and also when just the destination file is open (copying the code from Notepad instead).  Same results.
11. The remaining VBA code in the workbook (used for other purposes) is probably another 5,000 lines, spread across about 8 more modules.  I've certainly worked with workbooks with much larger code bases than that, so I don't think there is an Excel workbook limit I'm reaching.
12. My PC has 64 GB of RAM.  No other intensive applications are running and the Task Manager says I'm hitting less than 10 - 20% memory usage on my PC.

I greatly appreciate your help.